# Java && Error "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String"

Tags: java

```
 if(pro_name.getText() && pro_price.getText() && pro_count.getText())
 {
 }
```

Am getting an error in eclipse java

**The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String**

Comment: Can you provide more description about what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!pro_name.getText().isEmpty()
    && !pro_price.getText().isEmpty()
    && !pro_count.getText().isEmpty())
```

Conditions strictly require a boolean expression in java.

Answer (score 2):

&& operator is valid for checking boolean values

```
if(pro_name.getText()=="abc" && pro_price.getText().isEmpty() && pro_count.getText().equals("mango")){   }
```

above one is sample one...this wont produce compilation errors.

`isEmpty()`, `equals()`, `equalsIgnoreCase()`,`contains()` ==> these are the permissible operations on strings, each of them returns boolean values( `true` or `false`)

`==` this checks for equality and hence returns boolean true or false value

Answer (score 1):

here `getText()` returns `String`, and in java `&&` operator is only defined for `boolean` not for `String`.

This is why eclipse is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use && (AND) operator for booleans. .getText() returns a string, which is not a boolean values. You need to do a checkup that returns a boolean to do this, for example:

```
if(!pro_name.getText().isEmpty() ...)
```

I.e., if the answer from getText() is not null it will be translated to true. and tjhe && comparison will work.

A tip is to set a variable to the answer from getText() so you can reuse it, instead of later (I am asuming) you get the text again. I.e.:

```
var pro_name_result = pro_name.getText();
if(!pro_name_result.isEmpty() ...) {
```